# A Reviews Page is Showing root Index.php instead of Template-Page

Tags: theme-development, page-template

**Issue:** The root index.php file is showing up instead of my created template-name.php.

**What I have done to try and fix:** Delete and create a new reviews page with the routename of "reviews". Check my template-page.php to see if I forgot something. 
Changed the template to the default template for the reviews page and it gives the same index.php.

**Other Important Info:**

I have a development environment where the routename works ([www.developmentsite.test/reviews](http://www.developmentsite.test/reviews)), and shows my template-page.
I have also created a page, with a different route, on my production site that uses the review template-page I created and works as well([www.productionsite.com/test-page](http://www.productionsite.com/test-page)).

**What I need help with:** I need ([www.productionsite.com/reviews](http://www.productionsite.com/reviews)) to show my template-page that I created.

**What I think is the issue:** There is something wrong with the routename /reviews because even creating a brand new page with that routename, it gives me the index.php root file while using any other routenames, it gives me my default page.php file.

Comment: What is reviews? It's important information that's missing from the question.

Comment: @JacobPeattie It's a page, I created a page named "reviews".

Comment: Have you got a custom post type named reviews?

Comment: @JacobPeattie oh yes, I do. Damn, I didn't even think of that. What are my options then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you mentioned that you had a `reviews` post type. This means that `/reviews/` will be the default URL for listing that post type, and this will use index.php as per the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). If you're trying to list reviews, then my first suggestion would be to just use the post type archive, and create `archive-reviews.php` to markup and style them.

If you do ultimately need a static page that list reviews, rather than the post type archive, then set the `has_archive` property of the post type to `false`. Then `/reviews/` won't exist anymore, and you can use it as the slug for a new page instead.

Comment: To reiterate, this is the correct solution to my problem. I apologize for taking a while to accept the answer.